# Files that describe cpu architectures exhaustively to write retargetable compilers

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler-construction, compilation, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am looking for one file F[i] per cpu-architecture A[i] (x86-32, x86-64, ARM, Itanium, etc). Each file F[i] would provide enought information about the architecture A[i] (registers, instruction set, semantics, etc), so that it would be possible, for any language L, to write a program P that takes any F[i] and generate a compiler-optimizer C[i] for the language L to native A[i].
Of course the knowledge of P about A[i] comes from F[i] exclusively.

Each F[i] should contain enought information so that for any given compiler C' for the language L to native A[i], we can write a P that produces a C[i] performing as well as C'.
Ideally, F[i] files would be written in a same language DescL able to describe future cpu-architectures.

Does such files F[i] exist (at least for the most common cpu-architectures) ? Then where can I download them ? 
Does such an DescL already exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be interested in the Zephyr "National Compiler Infrastructure" project; see 128.143.136.29/zephyr/  [I'd put in a real link but StackOverflow won't allow me to do this for this host.  The link is valid in spite of SO's opinion.  No, I don't understand why it doesn't have a nice symbolic name, but hey, its not my site.].

They made serious attempts to define machine description formalisms, and I believe they encoded a number of "common" machine instruction sets.   You should read their papers before you make any choices.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. So there is already CSDL, a family of description languages. CSDL is composed of SLED, PLUNGE, Calling Convention Languages, and the most complex part : lambda-RTL. (I am still reading all the links ...)

Comment: Your link was very interesting. Unfortunately it seems that the Zephyr project is no more active, whether it be your link or http://www.zephyr-software.com/

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Try contacting user Norman Ramsey  user:41661  http://stackoverflow.com/users/41661/norman-ramsey, who was of the key contributors.

Answer (score 4):

Joao Dias proved that for code generation at least, this problem is undecidable.  That is, for general machine architectures, no such program P can exist.  He also developed heuristics that are completely effective for typical machine architectures.  I recommend that you read [his dissertation](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~dias/dissertation/dissertation.pdf), which also reviews some of the large body of work that has been done on this problem.

You will find some related tools and descriptions associated with the [New Jersey Machine-Code Toolkit](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/toolkit) and the [Lambda-RTL](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/lrtl/download.html) specification language.  The specifications themselves are probably in a state of disarray, and Dr Dias is more likely to have specifications that are accurate and up to date.

The Zephyr web pages are very old, definitely obsolete, and should not be linked to.
But you could read [our papers](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/index.html) :-)

Answer (score 0):

- I know of no such database
- The nearest public such database that I know of would be the processor descriptions used by GCC. They mix the processor description with some code to handle some aspects of the code generation in a non data driven way.

Comment: I don't know of one either, but that doesn't mean they don't exist. There's lots of ignorance on the planet; telling people you don't know isn't helpful.   I think your answer would be much better if you explained why you thought they might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a thing, I believe this is far too abstract and complicated for a feasible P to exist.

I believe any useful F would effectively be a description of translations between a common intermediate language and the individual CPU instruction set (even if that language is declarative rather than a traditional compiler). Have a look at [LLVM's TableGen](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html), which is used to declare a lot of information about backends. AFAIK it's still not sufficient for describing architectures in their entirety, and apparently quite complicated to work with.

I do not see how P would know anything about L, but it would need that knowledge to create a compiler C[i].  Unless of course you create P specifically to know about L, at which point P becomes specific to a single L, and is effectively a traditional compiler front end, which is nothing new. The only difference is that you're writing a program for emitting the compiler, but I do not see how this saves you anything over just writing `C''` like someone wrote `C'` beforehand. (Parsing is a much simpler and smaller problem, hence successful advances, in parser generation. Despite this, parser generators are at best competitive with hand-written-by-experts parsers both in implementation effort and quality.) Alternatively, make P an AI and teach it compiler construction, but that's not possible with the current state of AI, and then you gotta find a way to teach P the languages (read: still no free compilers for you).

Apart from that, a compiler has to know **a lot** more than just CPU instructions. OS services, ABIs, and executable formats are just three of many nontrivial problems they face. I have similar doubts about applying a similar solution to those issues. The good old "decouple front end and back end" trick is almost as efficient in terms of effort, obviously much more possible, and makes much more sense to me.